# My newly created Swift decoder (for some old Obj-c persisted UserDefaults data) is getting nil for some specific existing and stored String field

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, data-migration

**Context:**

I've been given the task of creating a persisted UserDefaults data importer from an old version of some app our team created some time ago.
That app was created using ObjectiveC, and some kind of "old school data modeling" (not by me or even the current team).
The new app is an expectably shiny SwiftUI Swift modern application, but still, when at boot time it needs to detect this possible old persisted data and then being able to import it.

**Problem:**

When parsing/decoding the old UserDefaults, this (optional) offending field lives into some bplist stored in said UserDefaults. While allegedly this field seems to be a NSMutableString, it always gives nil when tried to be decoded.
I've "reverse engineered" parts of the bplist file where all these data fields are stored, and I have obtained this (field renamed) object:

EDIT:
The next data below is the transformation from "compressed" bplist object in memory onto Data and then onto ASCII using plutil -p
The moment of this memory capture is RIGHT before the "li" crashing/nil line while using a Xcode debugger breakpoint:

```
2 => {
  "_de" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x600001b21ae0 [0x1e76f0000]>{value = 4}
  "_or" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x600001b21b20 [0x1e76f0000]>{value = 3}
  "$class" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x600001b21b60 [0x1e76f0000]>{value = 9}
  "fa" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x600001b21b40 [0x1e76f0000]>{value = 5}
  "li" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x600001b21b80 [0x1e76f0000]>{value = 6}
  "tr" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x600001b21b00 [0x1e76f0000]>{value = 8}
}


4 => "Ca"           // Non crashing String

3 => "AT"          // Again non crashing String

9 => {
  "$classes" => [
    0 => "IVO"
    1 => "GenericVO"
    2 => "OFValueObject"
    3 => "NSObject"
  ]
  "$classname" => "IVO"
}

5 => 1         // Numeric value, it loads ok.

6 => {
  "$class" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x600001b21ba0 [0x1e76f0000]>{value = 7}
  "NS.string" => "S17"   // This is the unobtainable field
}

7 => {
  "$classes" => [
    0 => "NSMutableString"
    1 => "NSString"
    2 => "NSObject"
  ]
  "$classname" => "NSMutableString"
}

8 => "S2"           // Loads perfectly
```

This IVO Class is defined in the old objective C code with these members (among other stuff):

```
class IVO: NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding{


    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *_or;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *_de;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *fa;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *li;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tr;

    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
```

I have no idea or access to the decisions that lead to the beforementioned class naming/structure.

My new destination swift IVO class has these members (which try to mimic the original ones):

```
let _or: String
let _de: String
let fa: Int
let li: String
let tr: String
```

Also the decoder code inside this new recreated class is this one:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {

    _or = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "_or") as! String
    _de = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "_de") as! String
    fa = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "fa") as! Int

    tr = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "tr") as! String

    // Many diferent types of cast have been tried here
    // Just asking with no-cast returns a nil into l

    if let l = (coder.decodeObject(forKey: "li") as? NSMutableString)   
    {
        li = l as String
    }
    else
    {
        // I'm ENTERING THROUGH THIS BRANCH... the "if let" is to avoid the crash
        li = ""
    }
    
    // I wish I could use something as simple as this
    //li = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "li") as! String // or NSMutableString (?)

    super.init()
    
}
```

EDIT: Here I put the snippet of code that calls the IVO class to decode data:

```
var encodedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Fa")
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(MY_PROJECT_NAME.IVO.self, forClassName: "IVO")
var arrayObjects = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: IVO.self, from: encodedData as! Data)
```

**Note:**

I changed tr object reading order just to see if it had something to do, and apparently not, the tr field is properly read.

**QUESTION:**

How should I check more things to be able to read the "li" attribute that is currently returning nil? (and thus Crashing/not getting the expected stored data ?)

**Note:**

In the "exploded" bplist I posted above I can actually see how this "li" attribute seems not to be a normal String as its siblings, but a "NSMutableString" (with its class definition deferred one step with node '7'). Is there a particulary way to read this String info living in this kind of "redefined/NSMutableString" bplist node ?

It's a complex question and I might be editing some of the details/typos, or even adding more info if someone asks me to do it.

All help will be welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: `coder.decodeObject(forKey: "li")` show what type in console? What about using a breakpoint, and see/test in debugguer/console possible "as?"

Comment: "one field stored into the old UserDefaults that, while allegedly being a NSMutableString, it always gives nil when tried to be decoded" I doubt it. There is no such thing as an NSMutableString in user defaults. Please show the (old) code that stored that bit of data into user defaults to begin with.

Comment: That's the point, I don't have this code handy

Comment: po coder.decodeObject(forKey: "li") yields nil 

NOTE: I've added some explanation on the original post to clear up that what I originally posted is the actual object in memory right before xcode debugger step crashes/obtains nil.

Comment: Can you show the top-level code where you're getting this data out of `UserDefaults`? Specifically, this doesn't look like `UserDefaults` data, but a keyed archive that you may be pulling as data out of `UserDefaults`, then decoding. If that's the case, we'll need to see how you're using `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to decode the data. (Specifically, if `requiresSecureCoding` is enabled, which is the default, you're going to need to whitelist types like `NSMutableString` in order to be able to decode them. Can give more info with confirmation.)

Comment: @ItaiFebrer I added some more info on the original question regarding the topics you commented (and maybe some others). You're probably right, while debugging UserDefaults data acquisition it seems there's bplist encoded info inside the UserDefaults object. I didn't remember UserDefaults data managing to be like this when I used it in the past...

Comment: Could `li` value be optional, or is there a real non nil value inside it? Do you have maybe a real sample value (with no sensitive data) of `Data` to share?

Comment: There is an actual value, it's not nil... The UserDefaults containt a "Fa" node which is a full string of HEX, which I decode successfully and then I see how it contained a bplist, which I pipe out to a .bin file onto my local disk, and then I use plutil -p to decode it (Again, successfully). The direct output of this plutil -p binary decoding is the 1st data scheme of my original post. (I renamed sensitive data to 2 letter variable names).

Comment: Unrelated but your .bin work a plutil could be done simplified by writing  `encodedData` into a temp File as `Data`, then just do `let dict = try NSDictionary(contentsOf: urlOfTheEncodedDataJustWritten, error: ()); print(dict)` and if might be better presented too...